# Libgdx Box2d 60fps but Stuttering

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

Okay so I have a side scrolling game where I use box2d for the physics. My camera focuses on the player and only the player moves. The player moves by using box2d, I have set the linear velocity and everything has a friction of 0. The obstacles seem to stutter back and forth every once in a while and sometimes it seems to last forever or from the very beginning it is stuttering.

The way the player's sprite is rendered is that the player has a update method that gets the location of the corresponding box2d body and stores that location for it to be used in its render method. I do use PPM and the everything else is a static body.

I have a sensor following behind the player that will detect and blocks going off screen and reuse these blocks as more obstacles and I do similar things for the background and the floor so the player can run forever. There are only 2 background object 2 floor object and 12 block objects. I made sure that there is no costly operations in my render methods and I do not create any new objects outside of the initial load of the state. 
Using

```
Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()
```

I have determined that the fps goes between 60 and 61 so I don’t believe this is a lag issue and I have no idea how to fix this.

Main Render method:

```
 public void render(){
    //clear screen
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //set camera to follow player
    cam.position.set(player.getPosition().x * B2DVars.PPM + NinjaJumper.V_WIDTH / 4,
            NinjaJumper.V_HEIGHT/2, 0);
    cam.update();

    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    //render the background
    for (int i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++){
        backgrounds[i].render(sb);
    }

    //render the player
    player.render(sb);

    if(haveBlocks) {
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            blocks[i].render(sb);
        }
    }

    //render the ground
    for (int i = 0; i < ground.length; i++){
        ground[i].render(sb);
    }

    sb.setProjectionMatrix(hudCam.combined);
    hud.render(sb);

    if(debug) {
        //set camera to follow player
        b2dCam.position.set(player.getPosition().x + (NinjaJumper.V_WIDTH / 4) / B2DVars.PPM,
                (NinjaJumper.V_HEIGHT / 2) / B2DVars.PPM, 0);
        b2dCam.update();
        b2dr.render(world, b2dCam.combined);
    }
}
```

Player render and update methods:

```
public void update(float dt){
    animation.update(dt);
    sprite.setRegion(animation.getFrame());
    sprite.setCenter(body.getPosition().x * B2DVars.PPM,
            body.getPosition().y * B2DVars.PPM  - 5);
}

public void render(SpriteBatch sb){
    sb.begin();
    sprite.draw(sb);
    sb.end();
}
```

So can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, I've spent days looking at this and I can't figure it out.

edit pack.pack:

```
pack.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Linear,Linear
repeat: none
mainpage
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 281
  size: 960, 720
  orig: 960, 720
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
ground
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 140
  size: 600, 139
  orig: 600, 139
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
treeM
  rotate: false
  xy: 603, 38
  size: 139, 241
  orig: 139, 241
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
tree
  rotate: false
  xy: 744, 39
  size: 137, 240
  orig: 137, 240
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
treeS1
  rotate: false
  xy: 883, 42
  size: 133, 237
  orig: 133, 237
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
treeS
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 19
  size: 67, 119
  orig: 67, 119
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
button1
  rotate: false
  xy: 70, 114
  size: 70, 24
  orig: 70, 24
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
button2
  rotate: false
  xy: 70, 88
  size: 70, 24
  orig: 70, 24
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
platform
  rotate: false
  xy: 963, 969
  size: 32, 32
  orig: 32, 32
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
block
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 16, 16
  orig: 16, 16
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1

pack2.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Linear,Linear
repeat: none
treeM1
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 625
  size: 255, 378
  orig: 255, 378
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
treeH
  rotate: false
  xy: 258, 540
  size: 200, 463
  orig: 200, 463
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
ninja1
  rotate: false
  xy: 460, 503
  size: 500, 500
  orig: 500, 500
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
ninja2
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 500, 500
  orig: 500, 500
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
ninja3
  rotate: false
  xy: 503, 1
  size: 500, 500
  orig: 500, 500
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1

pack3.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Linear,Linear
repeat: none
ninja4
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 503
  size: 500, 500
  orig: 500, 500
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
ninja5
  rotate: false
  xy: 503, 503
  size: 500, 500
  orig: 500, 500
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
ninja6
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 500, 500
  orig: 500, 500
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
ninja7
  rotate: false
  xy: 503, 1
  size: 500, 500
  orig: 500, 500
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1

pack4.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Linear,Linear
repeat: none
mainpage1
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 900, 600
  orig: 900, 600
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1

pack5.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Linear,Linear
repeat: none
ninja8
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 500, 500
  orig: 500, 500
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

Comment: are you using TexturePacker with trimming?

Comment: I'm using the TexturePacker but I don't know what trimming is.

Comment: in TP you have something like "Trim mode" have you set it to somethnig else that **none** ?

Comment: I don't see anything that says trim mode. All my settings are default except min filter and mag filter but I've had this problem before I changed these.

Comment: ok then please share to me your .atlas / .pack file

Comment: I added the contents of the .pack file to my post. Not sure if there another way to share files on stackoverflow.

Comment: I wonder if you solved it in the meantime...

Answer (score -1):

There are two possible areas possible to be a source of stuttering - rendering and physics.

When you are using **trimming** in TexturePacker you need to handle **offset** during drawing but it is not your case - please notice you have all **offsets zeroes** and **size** is exactly the same as **orig**.

You should focus on your physics. There is well known bug in box2D appears when two bodies - small and big - are in contact and causing stuttering. Please try these two things:

- use [Box2D debug renderer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Box2DDebugRenderer.html) to see if your bodies are stuttering or just a sprite
- try to log out **body.getPosition()** in every step to see if **x** or **y** is changing in proper way

If it is problem with physics the solution is to set fixture material restitution to **0** and try to **setLinearDamping** to avoid a little moves

Comment: Okay I think the problem is with physics cause the bodies do stutter but how much and when do i setLinearDamping? Is it at the create or in all updates and by how much?

Comment: start with modifying material restitution. If it won't help try to test how much dumping you need starting from let say 1 - you need to do this once when creating body

Comment: I have everything restitution set to one and the dampening I've tried from 1 - 0.025 but the stutter is still there even when the dampening slows my guy to a crawl I can still see the stutter

Comment: restitution should be set to **zero** - damping as little as possible because yes it will "stopping" you character

Comment: Sorry I meant restitution is set to zero, and I've test all the way to 0.00001f for dampening and it still stutters. Should I just keep trying smaller number?

Comment: I think you should not. Last thing comes to my mind is that your bodies are just to small. Maybe try to do them bigger?

Comment: I've tried decreasing my PPM by as low as 10 and it's still stutter.

Comment: yup but decreasing PPM you still got very very big one body and second relatively very small - try to just modify size of the small (player/obstacle) body. If it won't help I'm afraid I don't have any other idea for this time.

Comment: I've tried playing around with the sizes but I'm having no luck, but thanks for taking the time to try and help